# Quick Debug Infos in CDB with Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

as you (hopefully) can see in the picture, debugging a QFile object with CDB in Qt Creator looks something like this. Notice the path in the middle.

[image]

For my own classes the debugger shows me there address in this field. I recon that's something that can be changed into some user defined content. I hope I am right and I hope someone here knows (and shares) how. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to mandate how user-defined data types are displayed during debugging, it looks like you need to write a QT Debugging Helper for the specified type.  Documentation can be found here for the current version of Qt Creator:

http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-helpers.html

It looks like Debugging Helpers can be implemented in C++ or Python for most platforms.